# How to pass on a lambda that produces a list to a procedure that expects a list?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have the following procedures:

```
(define (remove-first f)
    (rest f))


(define (sty f)
  (remove-first (lambda (x) (map f x))))


(define (square x)
     (* x  x))

(define new-func (sty square))
(new-func (list 1 2 3))
```

Here, I want to create a function `sty` that takes in a function, applies it to a list and then removes the first element of the list. However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
rest: expects a non-empty list; given: (lambda (a1) ...)
```

I understand the error but am not sure how I can pass my lambda (which will produce a list) to `remove-first`

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that definitions of `remove-first`, `square`, `new-func` and `(new-func (list 1 2 3))` are parts of the assignment and you can't change them.

In that case, function `sty` can't return a list. It has to return [closure](https://docs.racket-lang.org/racket-glossary/index.html#%28part._.Closure%29). Closure is a lambda function that "remembers" variables from the environment, where it was created. So, your function will "remember" the value of `f` and you just have to call it with the list to get the expected result.

This is a default behaviour of `lambda`, so you just have to change the order of `remove-first` and `lambda`:

```
(define (remove-first f)
  (rest f))

(define (sty f)
  (lambda (x) (remove-first (map f x))))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define new-func (sty square))

(new-func (list 1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do in `sty` is actually to `compose` two functions (chaining them) - the `remove-first` and your lambda:

```
(define (remove-first f)
  (rest f))

(define (sty f)
  (compose remove-first (lambda (x) (map f x)))))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define new-func (sty square))

(new-func (list 1 2 3)) ;;=> '(4 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

`new-func` is supposed to be a function.
So, `(sty square)` must be a function.
That means that `sty` must have the form

```
(define (sty f)
  (lambda (x) ...))
```

Adding "map `f` over `x` and remove the first element":

```
(define (sty f)
  (lambda (x) (rest (map f x))))
```

Note that, unless `f` has any side effects, it is a waste of work to apply it to the list's head and discard the result, and it makes more sense to throw the head away first:

```
(define (sty f)
  (lambda (x) (map f (rest x))))
```